# Check if sum of two amounts is equal to a certain total with some tolerance

Tags: python, math

How can I check if the result of multiplying two amounts is equal to a certain total  give or take a few cents. For example: 5.57 * 2.92 = 16.2644 and 3.25 * 5 = 16.25.
I am increasing the first amount which is the stake by 0.01 each time to try find the closest amount to the total, the second amount does not change.

Comment: It seems pretty straightforward -- can we see your code?

Comment: So you want to calculate the total stake involved?

Comment: @AamirAdnan I am calculating the potential profit if a price on a horse drops after you backed it, based on ticks, so say you back at 5.0 and the horse drops to 4.8, I want to show how much you can lay it for to turn your liability to profit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're making financial-type calculations in Python (or any programming language), you do *not* want to use floating point numbers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

Instead, be sure to at least use the `decimal` module, which will give you arbitrary-precision decimal numbers (http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

As for your actual problem:

```
from decimal import Decimal

r1 = Decimal("5.57") * Decimal("2.92")
r2 = Decimal("3.25") * Decimal("5")
epsilon = Decimal("0.01")

if abs(r1 - r2) <= epsilon:
    print "Almost equal!"
```

Comment: It does at least in part: 0.01 is not representable in binary, meaning the OP's calculations will start accumulating errors very early on if they do use floats.

Answer (score 2):

decimal is good.

But to compare two floats within a tolerance:

```
tolerance = 0.04
if abs(number1 - number2) < tolerance:
    print('the numbers are close')
```

Comment: thanks, is there any advantage to using floats instead of the decimal as suggested by Max Noel?

Comment: It's the tiniest bit faster and easier to write, but the general recommendation here is `decimal` due to accuracy issues.